# How can I run my Lint custom rules in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

I have coded Lint customs rules properly and they return nice report as I wanted, but they don't in Android Studio, even if I don't change anything and I just run "Analyze/Inspect Code".

Anyone could help me?

Thanks!

Comment: run "gradlew lint :app"

Comment: but I know that the command './gradlew app:lint' works properly, what I meant is that I would like to see lint report directly from Androd Studio, inside the console!